# What type of Exception is thrown for using inactive Users?

Tags: apex, exception

I've got a Before Update trigger that attempts to assign a new Owner on Accounts and I'm trying to handle the potential exception where the new Owner is inactive. I can cause the error in testing (An operation was performed with an inactive user.) but the logs do not reveal the error and its exception type.

I don't want to use an extra query to check Users active status but if there's no exception that can be trapped, then that's the only choice. Any ideas on how to catch that exception?

Comment: I did find a reasonable hack to avoid the SOQL query by adding a checkbox formula field to the Account that provides the Active status of the potential new Owner. This can be reference in a trigger without an extra query.

Comment: are you doing this in a before trigger? If so, setting the ownerId to a member of Trigger.new won't throw the error until after the trigger concludes and only the user (or any apex that did a dml on the triggered object) will find out

Comment: In Spring '15, you will be able to update records owned by inactive Users - so maybe you could wait a month?

Comment: @crop1645 I suspected that populating Owner in before (with an sObject put) might be the problem with trapping the error since there's no actual DML. Where does one insert try-catch for before events then?

Comment: You can't do try-catch on the implicit update/insert done by before triggers. You have to test for error conditions yourself and do addError(..) on the trigger list member

Comment: Ah, then my use of the formula field is actually the most efficient way to test for active vs. inactive Users in a before trigger, at least when that option is available as a result of the User already being represented on the record (in our case it's the support rep to be assigned as Owner on Closed Won). Thanks @crop1645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread

1. You can't catch DML exceptions on the implicit insert/update performed on the SObject(s) used in `Trigger.new`. Only the "caller" of the trigger will see the error (that is, some other class/trigger doing explicit Apex DML, the user on the UI, or Dataloader/Api application)
2. Hence, you need to write code in the trigger (or related handler class) that tests for the inactive user and uses `addError(...)` on the related Trigger.new record.